# How to bind an event to a basic variable in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new in Backbone. Here is my question. I have a collection of song list and an index of current play song of this list in collection. The code is like :

```
var songCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        ...
        this.index = 0;
        ...
    },
    ...
    getNextSong:function(){
        ...
        this.index++;
        ...
    }

})
```

And there is a view to show the content of the current playing song. I want to update the view info when the current playing song changes.Below code doesn't work in view.

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function(options){
         this.options.on('change:index', this.render, this);

    }
)}
```

Nor does

```
this.listenTo(...);
```

Could someone tell an approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "change:[attribute]" (model, value, options) — when a specific attribute has been updated - [Events-catalog](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

Change events are triggered for changes inside models `attributes` hash, Changing random properties of a collection won't fire any events as far as I know.

You should better have a flag like `isPlaying` in the model's attributes, and listenTo it's change on collection from the view.

```js
var songModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    isPlaying: false
  }
});
var songCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: songModel
});

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change:isPlaying', this.render);
  },
  render: function(model, value, options) {
   if(value){
    //---------------^ this is the playing song, render it
   }
  }
});
```